# How can I open EPS files under Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, eps

How do I view EPS files? I heard that Adobe Acrobat supports them, but that didnt work for me...

I am using Windows 7 64 bit edition..

Answer (score 26):

EPS is encapsulated postscript. If you search for programs which can open postscript you will find a lot of them.

Some of them, in a random order, are:

- [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/) (really the classical answer)
- [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/). Large, but handles just about everything (but needs Ghostscript anyway).
- [Photoshop](http://www.photoshop.com/). Also quite large.
- [EPS viewer](http://download.cnet.com/EPS-viewer/3000-2193_4-11435982.html) (Which is the first link I got when I Googled on "win7 EPS viewer").

Comment: If you'll use GIMP, you may need to update it with Ghostscript (as mentioned above) per the following: https://superuser.com/questions/988847/how-do-i-open-an-eps-file-in-gimp-2-could-not-interpret-postscript-file

Comment: Looks like you can now use Adobe Acrobat reader also

Comment: The reference is Illustrator. And to convert to pdf Adobe Distiller should be used. You do understand that postscript is Corel and Adobe format?

Answer (score 12):

I open a blank Word document, and from insert option, choose pictures, browse and insert the eps file in my document.

Not a great solution if you want to edit the eps file, but good enough if all you want to do is view the file (I'm not installing 3rd party software just to view a file if I don't have to).

Comment: +1 for way more simpler than downloading a program just to see what is in my .eps file

Comment: Note that, since April 2017, this [is no longer possible](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Support-for-EPS-images-has-been-turned-off-in-Office-a069d664-4bcf-415e-a1b5-cbb0c334a840).

Answer (score 7):

I am surprised no one mentioned [Evince](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince). It handles everything - pdf, ps, eps. It comes by default on all linux distributions. It has a windows installer too on its [Downloads](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince/Downloads) page.

Comment: Never imagined how much I would miss evince before I had to work in Windows. Thanks for mentioning it here, I thought it's just for Linux.

Answer (score 6):

I have had no problems with Adobe Acrobat and a bit confused why it isn't working (EPS is supported in the latest few versions), however, I always used to use [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) which works with them - so you may want to try that.

Comment: +1 for GIMP since Photoshop ain't cheap to just open some files!

Answer (score 3):

Your question suggests Acrobat Reader can open an eps file. This is not exactly correct, To open an .eps file with acrobat, you need to import it. This requires a paid account:

From [the documentation](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/supported-file-formats-acrobat-reader.html)

```
Use File > Create PDF > From File
```

Answer (score 3):

[Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/en/download/) allows viewing *and editing* EPS files.

Comment: thats seems to only be true "out-of-the-box" for linux. on windows, however, it requires additional steps: http://clownfishcafe.blogspot.de/2014/05/importing-eps-files-into-inkscape.html

Answer (score 1):

If you have Photoshop, it should be able to open them.

Answer (score 1):

There is a port of Okular viewer from Linux KDE [to Windows](https://windows.kde.org/)

Answer (score 0):

I used [Scribus](http://www.scribus.net/canvas/Scribus) which is open source software. You should first install [GhostScript](http://www.ghostscript.com/). Scribus will automatically detect GhostScript an enable EPS support. Otherwise you have to add it afterwards through settings.