# How do I open an EPS file in GIMP 2? "Could not interpret PostScript file"

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, gimp, eps

I've created some EPS files in GIMP 2, but I can't open them back up. When I try, the "Import from PostScript" dialog comes up, but no matter what I do, when I proceed I get an error "could not interpret PostScript file".

I'm using Windows 7 x64/64-bit and GIMP `2.8.14`, also x64/64-bit.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Per the [GIMP EPS bug report on GNOME Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=689207#c32), you'll have to install Ghostscript (if you haven't done so already), then replace a DLL in GIMP with one from Ghostscript.

1. Install Ghostscript from the [Ghostscript download page](http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html). Be sure to get the **64 bit** version.
2. If GIMP is open, close it.
3. From the Ghostscript bin folder (`C:\Program Files\gs\gs9.18\bin` for me; your version number may be different), copy the `gsdll64.dll` file to the GIMP bin folder (`C:\Program Files\GIMP 2\bin\` for me).
4. In the GIMP bin folder, rename `libgs-8.dll` to `libgs-8.dll.backup`. You can revert back to this file in case something goes wrong.
5. Then, rename `gsdll64.dll` to `libgs-8.dll`.

The next time you run GIMP and open/import an EPS file, after the "Import from PostScript" dialog, the file will open as usual. =)

#### References

- [GIMP EPS bug report on GNOME Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=689207#c32)
- [Ghostscript download page](http://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html)

Comment: I vastly prefer the following approach: Do steps 1 and 2 above, then 3. Control panel => System => Advanced System settings and create an environment variable GS_PROG=C:\Program Files\gs<ghostscriptversion>\bin\gswin64.exe - and finally 4. restart Gimp. The file should now open fine. I prefer this approach because there is no "messing with gimp" keeping ghostscript and gimp entirely independent; which means gimp can be cleanly upgraded without having to remember to redo the exercise each time as you would have to with the above approach

Comment: @Pancho - I agree, a cleaner approach, but keep in mind you might have to update this environment variable if you update your ghost script version :-).

Comment: @TimHarker - 100% . If this is of concern to you then you could remove the version specific component of the ghost writer path when installing / upgrading eg. C:\gw\ which would mean the environment variable would not be affected and would thus not need to be changed.