# How to open this file? *.ps.gz

Tags: 7-zip, postscript, gz

Please somebody help me to open [this file](http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~ndm/PhDthesis.ps.gz)
. I am not able to open it/unzip it after downloading.I always get an error when I try to unzip using 7zip.

Comment: Downloads fine for me. Try again?

Comment: Check it its really gzip file, try to open it in text editor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**First the file's corrupt or not status:** It works for me when I download it:

```
toad:/home/hennes>wget www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~ndm/PhDthesis.ps.gz
--2016-02-26 07:57:37--  http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~ndm/PhDthesis.ps.gz
Resolving www.robots.ox.ac.uk (www.robots.ox.ac.uk)... 129.67.94.2
Connecting to www.robots.ox.ac.uk (www.robots.ox.ac.uk)|129.67.94.2|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 3369790 (3.2M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: `PhDthesis.ps.gz'

100%[======================================>] 3,369,790   8.83M/s   in 0.4s

2016-02-26 07:57:38 (8.83 MB/s) - `PhDthesis.ps.gz' saved [3369790/3369790]
```

Donwloaded via wget. Notice that it recognises the file as being gzipped ([application/x-gzip]). To save bandwidth many webservers serve gzip compressed information and many browsers can decompress this on the fly.

This means that one some browsers you can download a file.gz and when you save it is already decompressed. The file name does not always get adjusted for this.

Lets see what `file` thinks of the downloaded result:

```
toad:/home/hennes>file PhDthesis.ps.gz
PhDthesis.ps.gz: gzip compressed data, was "thesis.ps", from Unix, last modified: Wed May 19 20:15:48 1999
```

If it is a gzip file I should be able to uncompress it:

```
toad:/home/hennes>gzip -d PhDthesis.ps.gz
```

No errors reported.

Rerunning `file` in the uncompressed result:

```
toad:/home/hennes>file PhDthesis.ps
PhDthesis.ps: PostScript document text conforming at level 2.0
```

Looks like correct postscript to me. One final check, opening it in a text editor:

[image: vim postscipt file - in colour!]

Postscript al right. And even showing the traditional TeX to DVI to PS path. Classic.

**Secondly, how to open it**:

The classical way would be in ghostview, but there are many programs which should be able to handle postscript files. `gs` is probably installed on most unix like systems. If it is windows than see [this answer for ePS files](https://superuser.com/questions/109091/how-can-i-open-eps-files-under-windows-7).

Comment: Thank you! It worked when I used wget to download. The details in the answer were really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a raw PostScript file, not compressed at all. Just rename it to be *.ps and open the way you like.

Comment: Valid answer, but it would be a good idea to provide more information on this. As a starting point, see http://www.dontveter.com/qi/psandtex.html